# How to Add users in group

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Business Logic

- I am checking group is there or not and user also after that I am
  adding user in group but if user is already there user unable to add
  in group

  ```
  public async Task<List<AddUserToGroupResponseViewModel>> AddUserToGroupAsync(AddUserToGroupViewModel model)
               {
                   var checkStatus = new List<AddUserToGroupResponseViewModel>();

                   var checkGroup = await this.lmsMasterRepository.GetExistsAsync<Group>(a => a.Id == model.GroupId && !a.IsDeleted && a.IsActive).ConfigureAwait(false);
                   if (checkGroup == true)
                   {
                       var users = await this.lmsMasterRepository.GetAllUsersInGroup(model.GroupId).ConfigureAwait(false);
                       foreach (var values in model.UserId)
                       {
                           var result = await this.lmsMasterRepository.GetExistsAsync<User>(a => a.Id == values && !a.IsDeleted && a.IsActive && !users.Contains(values)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                           if (result == true)
                           {
                               var usergroup = new UserGroup()
                               {
                                   UserId = values,
                                   GroupId = model.GroupId,
                                   CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                               };
                               await this.lmsMasterRepository.CreateAsync<UserGroup>(usergroup).ConfigureAwait(false);
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               var status = new AddUserToGroupResponseViewModel()
                               {
                                   UserId = values,
                                   Status = "user unable to add",
                               };

                               checkStatus.Add(status);
                           }
                       }

                       if (await this.lmsMasterRepository.SaveAsync())
                       {
                           return checkStatus;
                       }

                       return checkStatus;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       return null;
                   }
               }
  ```

Repository level
I am taking users which is added in group

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetAllUsersInGroup(int groupId)
    {
        return await this.MasterContext.UserGroups.Where(a => a.GroupId == groupId).Select(x => x.UserId).AsQueryable().ToListAsync();
    }
```

I have tried this but they need batch calling I am not able to know about that

Comment: Why are you trying to add an already existing user ?
Is the user id unique in your user table ?

Comment: i am not adding existing user i am just checking

Comment: Where are you having trouble ? when adding a user ? when calling users ?

Comment: I need batch calling on that @Jesse